# Order By clause in PagingAndSortingRepository

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have and interface `StockRepository` extending `PagingAndSortingRepository`.
Here I have a method Query method namely:

`List<Stock> findByUserIdAndCustomerId(Integer userId, Integer customerId);`

Joining `Stock` I have `StockBilling` on `StockBilling.stock.id` and I want to modify my above method to order my results by StockBilling.balance due.
Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got this done by using following method name:

```
List<Stock> findByUserIdAndCustomerIdOrderByStockBillingId(Integer userId, Integer customerId);
```